# JSON: Append Array into Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

First of all, sorry for the long question. Thanks for reading.

I am new to PHP and I'm currently working on a game where I will be using JSON to store some data. I am trying to add an array into an array. Visual Explanation:

```
{
"saves": [
    {
        "save0":[
            {
                "health" : "100",
                "coins" : "50",
                "level" : "10"
            }
        ],
        "save1":[
            {
                "health" : "78",
                "coins" : "124",
                "level" : "15"
            }
        ]
    }
] }
```

The code above represents this `saves.json` example file. In this example the player has made 2 saves and has some preset data in there. The player hasn't played for a while and has kind of lost track of what his plans were in the latest save so he makes a new save.

He creates `"save2"` and plays for a bit, but then he takes a break and comes back and all of his data is lost due to the fact that the PHP file which loads and saves data doesn't find the file called `"save2"`. Well it's obvious. The `GenerateSave.php` got no message to create it.

The PHP file that loads the save loads the data like this:

```
<?php

    $requested_savename = $_POST["savename"];

    $jsondata = file_get_contents("saves.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $savesdata = "";

    foreach($json['saves'] as $saves)
    {
        foreach($saves[$requested_savename] as $save)
        {
            $savesdata .= $wdata['health'] . "\t";
            $savesdata .= $wdata['coins'] . "\t";
            $savesdata .= $wdata['level'] . "\t";   
        }
    }

    echo $savesdata;
?>
```

Basically, Unity3D requests this file and then get's the output and stores it in a string array which is split by every "\t" and can then identify which element indicates which value.

But that's basic, except that `$requested_savename` which is `save2` doesn't exist in the JSON file.

So my big question is. How can I possibly add the new save in there.

I want the JSON file to go from the example above, to this:

```
{
"saves": [
    {
        "save0":[
            {
                "health" : "100",
                "coins" : "50",
                "level" : "10"
            }
        ],
        "save1":[
            {
                "health" : "78",
                "coins" : "124",
                "level" : "15"
            }
        ],
        "save2":[
            {
                "health" : "100",
                "coins" : "10",
                "level" : "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have attempted this by using this code:

```
<?php

    $jsondata = file_get_contents("saves.json.json");
    $array_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $named_array = array(
        "save2" => array(
            array(
                "health" => "100",
                "coins" => "10",
                "level" => "1"
            )
        )
    );

    array_push($array_data['saves'], $named_array);

    $array_data['saves'] = $named_array;

    $final_data = json_encode($array_data);

    if(file_put_contents("test.json", $final_data, FILE_APPEND))
    {
        echo "0";
    }

?>
```

Thank you so much for reading. I wanted to make my question clear as I would probably be marked as duplicate for something that I have seen and didn't work for me. Whatever I Google every link is purple as that I have pretty much checked everything everywhere.

Thanks
- Jóhann B.Þ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the JSON from the file and decode it to `$array_data`, you need to get the id of the last save so you can increment it to use for the next one. You're trying to add "save2" now, but I assume you can add more saves after that.

```
$last_save_id = array_key_last($array_data['saves'][0]);
$next_save_number = substr($last_save_id, 4) + 1;
```

Then you can add your new save data to `$array_data` using that key.

```
$array_data['saves'][0]['save' . $next_save_number] = [
    "health" => "100",
    "coins" => "10",
    "level" => "1"
];
```

Then re-encode the extended `$array_data` and output to saves.json, overwriting the contents. Appending will rarely work correctly for this kind of thing, because concatenating JSON objects will not result in valid JSON.

```
file_put_contents('saves.json', json_encode($array_data));
```

---

If you're not using PHP 7.3 yet you won't have the `array_key_last()` function, so you'll need to use a different method to get the last save id. You can do it with `end()` and `key()`, for example.

```
$saves = $array_data['saves'][0];
end($saves);
$last_save_id = key($saves);
```

Comment: Yes, there we go that was exactly what exactly what I was looking for. Except that I requested to add the array with the brackets like in the example but I managed to do what I wanted to by changing the brackets to array( array( ) ); and insert the same lines that already where inside and I got what I wanted.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that extra array, sorry about that. Why is it there, though? Just curious. I would think each key in save would contain only one save object, so the array wrapping the object seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, actually the way I get the data I use foreach to get every save block and then I use a foreach for every element in the requested save "file". This works for me so I don't want to mess with that. Thanks for the help